# HP laptop temperature expectations

Tags: laptop, hp, temperature

HP 8440p laptop starts up at 50C and idles with at 51-52 (all temperatures Celcius).  Light use (Firefox) sees a max temp at 83.  When starting at 51, invoking Firefox drives temp to 67 and back down to 54  (51->67->54)

What is Firefox doing during the lengthy \dramatic transient: (51->67->54)
Is the idle-Firefox temperature reasonable? 
Does anyone else out there with an 8440p have similar experiences?

Heavy use (video transcoding) can drive temperatures so high as to cause shutdown.  Had to put in powersave mode to regulate CPU demand so as to not overheat-shutdown.

UPDATE:  [1-hour Disassembly revealed dust.  Does it makes sense to put it back together and expect reasonable cooling>  OR shall I wait and apply thermal paste to the CPU / heatsink? It is disassembled as far as possible without disturbing the factory thermal paste.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-orscDQEljs)

[Link to Gallery of before and after photos](https://postimg.org/gallery/zr5ufqke/4f2d9ecc/)

[image]

Compressed-air treatment:

[image]

Comment: That's a pretty old laptop (2010 from what I've read). Has the thermal paste ever been replaced?

Comment: Yes: 2010.  No thermal paste replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to be concerned. 83 degrees C is far more than high enough to prevent the function of the CD/DVD/BD drive and damage other hardware.  If your computer is out of warranty I strongly recommend you download the repair manual for the EliteBook 8440p directly from HP (you can call them and ask them to email you a link to the manual [which is on their webpage]) and use it to dismantle the entire case, clear/clean the copper cooling components where they pass air out of the case to the outside and if you have a static strap and a safe work area where you can remove the heatsink, then the poor thermal grease which HP applies and use Arctic MX-4 thermal grease (it has one of the highest thermal conductivity [W/mK] rates of any thermal grease) which will allow your hardware to run cooler than it did when the computer was brand new. I did exactly this to my HP HDX18t and it reduced the standard running temperatures by 40 degrees F (nearly 5 degrees C) and the heavy use temperatures have never reached over 155 degrees F [68 degrees C] with extremely heavy use (trying to push it to it's absolute limits) outdoors in the sun on a 90 degree F day (32.3 degrees C).  As for Firefox causing such an extreme problem with your computer I would recommend re-installing it to ensure it is correctly downloaded and installed `sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox` as it sounds (from your description) as though Firefox may be part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience: Firefox was chosen for the test case because it should moderately exercise computing cycles and is  commonly used: I am open to other testing.    Wondering if I should go with Artic MX-4 or the Thermal Grizzly Kryonaut: https://www.amazon.com/Thermal-Grizzly-Kryonaut-Grease-Paste/dp/B00ZJS8Q6S/ref=sr_1_2?

Comment: The Thermal Grizzly product may be as capable as it claims, but the problem is that no company or group  tests thermal grease & shows results to ensure it meets the standards it claims.  12.5 W/mK is so far above all other available thermal greases that it seems almost impossible to believe.  The Arctic MX-4 has a similar problem in terms of testing, but the reviews by many, many companies and the enormous volume of awards it's been given made it my choice: https://www.arctic.ac/us_en/mx-4.html -click "Awards" .  The Thermal Grizzly Kryonaut shows only 1 award and only on overclockers.co.uk

Comment: I failed to say (in the above) that the Thermal Grizzly Kryonaut product did not exist when I made the thermal grease purchase so it could not have been the product I used (4 years ago).

Comment: So shall it be: Artic MX-4 ordered and will arrive Monday.  Even if the Kryonaut is a better product, I am inclined to rely on experience.

Comment: Here is the effect of Arctic MX4 on a Gizmo 2 (I have 2, one with MX4 and 1 I have not applied it to yet):  1) With MX4 https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-1lAPlHMTDgM0lCeVI1SGhpN0k  (39.45 degrees C)  2) Without MX4 (factory gel still present) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-1lAPlHMTDgSGFGclZ6Y0V1cEk  temp = 57.22 degrees C) As you can see, there is a 17.77 degree C drop with the MX4 applied.  The slightly higher RAM use seen in the W/O MX4 picture was due to Linux Mint running it's update check (which is not a resource intensive program). So, I'd say you have made a good choice.

Comment: After disassembly, dust inspection \ removal.  Does it make sense to to leave the factory thermal paste and run the machine or wait for tomorrow's delivery of thermal paste and apply it?  It took me one hour to diassemble and will probably take that amount of time to re-assemble.

Comment: The Arctic MX4 is so much more effective at passing heat to the cooling device that I would suggest putting it to use in the computer, especially since you already have it partially disassembled.   Glad to see that you've found what may have been one of the major sources of your cooling problem (the dust build up).  When you do so you'll be able to see just how poor the cooling grease is that HP uses and can do away with it then.